# Same website, multiple servers

Tags: apache-httpd, load-balancing

I have a single server with a folder that contains my website with Apache, with a database in MySQL that contains some of my website data.

Now my question is, say that millions of users are using my website, and I want to lessen the load on my server by getting another server to share the load. How is this done?

In other words: How are services like Facebook managed with a single website and many, many servers? What is the paradigm for that?

It's just out of curiosity, I want to know how this works.

Comment: The term is "load balancing". Depends on the software, but usually some form of reverse proxy is used, such as [nginx](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/load_balancing.html).

Comment: to add to muru's answer, facebook and wikipedia user layers of computer to distribute incomming queries, information between database and so on. this is waht people call 'cloud computing'. try googlin "owncloud" and search for how-to. do not yield to despair.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Any additional information is highly appreciated :)

Comment: `haproxy` is a popular load balancer.

Comment: Also you can use a CDN http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19568411/list-of-facebook-cdn-addresses